# VBA Loop thru different worksheet & table to format alignment, column width & etc

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I've 4 different worksheet & different table. I trying to change the formatting using loop for all the worksheet but the range defined below is giving an error -

> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

Data I have already in table form.

```
Dim WSHT As Worksheet
    For Each WSHT In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    WSHT.Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 50
    Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Selection.WrapText = True
    Selection.Font.Name = "GE Inspira Sans"
    Selection.Font.Size = 9
    Dim ALLTAB As ListObject
    For Each ALLTAB In WSHT.ListObjects
    Range("[[#All],[Customer Name]]").ColumnWidth = 20
    Range("[[#All],[Customer Name]]").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next ALLTAB
Next WSHT
```

was using the below for formatting but I've 26 columns for update for each worksheet.

```
Range("OSD_TABLE_1[[#All],[Customer Name]]").ColumnWidth = 20
Range("OSD_TABLE_1[[#All],[Customer Name]]").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

Comment: Your `Range` objects are not qualified, so they assume `ActiveSheet`. Those lines are not aware they are in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the lines as

`Dim WSHT As Worksheet`

`For Each WSHT In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

`WSHT.UsedRange.RowHeight = 50`

`WSHT.UsedRange.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter`

`WSHT.UsedRange.WrapText = True`

`WSHT.UsedRange.Font.Name = "GE Inspira Sans"`

`WSHT.UsedRange.Font.Size = 9`

`Dim ALLTAB As ListObject`

`For Each ALLTAB In WSHT.ListObjects`

`ALLTAB.ListColumns("Customer Name").Range.ColumnWidth = 20`

`ALLTAB.ListColumns("Customer Name").Range.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft`

`Next ALLTAB`

`Next WSHT`